# QGIS Coverity Scan

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Can anyone clarify/tell me if the QGIS Coverity Scans (https://scan.coverity.com/projects/qgis-qgis) include plugin source code for plugins listed on https://plugins.qgis.org/?

If not, the Plugin page mentions that for a plugin to be listed on the site it must first be approved? What sort of security checking is in the process before it is listed? And is this approval only done for the initial upload of each plugin or for each update as well?

Answer (score 3):

No the Coverity scans don't include any of the 3rd party plugins.  It's only for the core C++ code.

There isn't any automatic security scanning done on plugins.  Plugins are approved by moderators, such as myself.  Generally we have a quick look over the code, check to make sure all the info is there, has an icon, etc.  Plugins are normally approved on each upload however a author can be trusted and plugins are auto approved.